# Add repeat count column to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a pandas dataframe with a list of courses that have been attempted: the ID of the student, the course ID, the term it was attempted, and the grade they received.  It looks sort of like:

```
Student ID       Course ID   Academic Term    Final Grade   
N99999           MAT101      201501           2.0 
N99999           MAT101      201509           2.5
N11111           CHE101      201609           3.0
N11111           PSY101      201601           0.0
N11111           PSY101      201701           2.0
```

I am interested in analyzing their grades and whether students improved by repeating a course.

To do so, I would like to add an 'attempt' column, where the row with the lowest term value for each combined course and ID number would get a 1, the next a 2, etc.

```
Student ID       Course ID   Academic Term    Final Grade  Attempt 
N99999           MAT101      201501           2.0          1
N99999           MAT101      201509           2.5          2
N11111           CHE101      201609           3.0          1
N11111           PSY101      201601           0.0          1
N11111           PSY101      201701           2.0          2
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for a standard Partition. There are several ways to do this but I've been doing it the below way. Try the below (note I changed/condensed some of the data):

```
df
```

Output:

```
student_id course_id academic_term  final_grade
0       n999    mat101        201501          2.0
1       n999    mat101        201509          2.5
2       n111    che101        201609          3.0
3       n111    psy101        201601          0.0
4       n111    psy101        201701          2.0
```

Input

```
df['attempt'] = df.sort_values('academic_term').groupby(['student_id', 'course_id'], sort=False).cumcount()+1
```

Output:

```
student_id course_id academic_term  final_grade  attempt
0       n999    mat101        201501          2.0        1
1       n999    mat101        201509          2.5        2
2       n111    che101        201609          3.0        1
3       n111    psy101        201601          0.0        1
4       n111    psy101        201701          2.0        2
```